# AWS Aurora and PipelineDB

Tags: postgresql, amazon-aurora, pipelinedb

Wanted to know if `PiplelineDB` extension will work with AWS Aurora PostgreSQL-compatible DB. Does anyone know if there are plans on the road-map to support this?

Answer (score 0):

No current plans that I'm aware of, but you can request this from the AWS Aurora team if it's something you want. Technically, PipelineDB is a standard extension for PostgreSQL, so this should be pretty easy from a technical standpoint.